# Can we construct a matrix $A$ and $B$ with given eigenvalues such that $A + B$ will have eigenvalues $(c_1, \ldots, c_n)$?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Let be $A, B$ two matrices $n \times n$ with respective eigenvalues $(a_1, \ldots, a_n)$ and $(b_1, \ldots, b_n)$, let be $C = A + B$ and $(c_1, \ldots, c_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Under which conditions on $A, B$ and $(c_1, \ldots, c_n)$ do we have that $C$ have $(c_1, \ldots, c_n)$ as eigenvalues ?

First, I tried to consider $A, B$ diagonalizable in the same basis, so that I could just say: $\forall i \in [[1, n]], c_i = a_i + b_i$ would suffice.

But I have no idea how to go to get a necessary condition.

Preferably, I am trying to avoid Jordan normal form.

Comment: Your solution works also for $\overline c = \alpha \overline a +\beta \overline b$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such questions are research questions. An exercise from Horn and Johnson 2 reveals that unless there are special properties of the matrices involved and more conditions are given, then nothing special happens.

Consider: $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1-\alpha& 1\\ \alpha(1-\alpha)-1& \alpha\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix} 1+\alpha& 1\\ -\alpha(1+\alpha)-1& -\alpha\end{bmatrix}$. The eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are independent of $\alpha$, but the spectral radius of $A+B$ is unbounded as $\alpha\to\infty$.

Another way to see my point is: specifying the eigenvalues of $A$, $B$, $C$ without constraints whatsoever is too weak an assumption to get interesting results. And once you do impose constraints, then things go to the shadow realm of research.